# Can you gain stream entry by focusing on the clinging and stress going on at the five clinging aggregates?

Tags: enlightenment, stream-entry, five-skandas

If I see the clinging and the stress going on at the five clinging aggregates can that propel me into stream entry?

Like say I see that clinging is going on at the five clinging aggregates and I see that it's causing stress can that take me to enlightenment or is another method needed like seeing the rise and fall of the aggregates, or practicing the silavant: http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.122.than.html sutta.

Is it just a good overall practice anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Meditating on the five aggregates and seeing the three characteristics of impermanence, stress, and non-self, leads all the way to Arahatship. In the words of the Anattalakhana Sutta:

> "What do you think, monks — Is form constant or inconstant?"
>
> "Inconstant, lord."
>
> "And is that which is inconstant easeful or stressful?"
>
> "Stressful, lord."
>
> "And is it fitting to regard what is inconstant, stressful, subject to
>   change as: 'This is mine. This is my self. This is what I am'?"
>
> "No, lord."
>
> (Similarly with the other aggregates)
>
> "Seeing thus, the well-instructed disciple of the noble ones grows
>   disenchanted with form, disenchanted with feeling, disenchanted with
>   perception, disenchanted with fabrications, disenchanted with
>   consciousness. Disenchanted, he becomes dispassionate. Through
>   dispassion, he is fully released. With full release, there is the
>   knowledge, 'Fully released.' He discerns that 'Birth is ended, the
>   holy life fulfilled, the task done. There is nothing further for this
>   world.'"
>   http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.059.than.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get enlightened by getting rid of clinging and craving. I.e. when a contract or formation gives arise to a sensation be equanimous without reaction knowing its true nature.